# How to create 3-D Tensors in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If you know about the Christoffel symbols, that's what I'm trying to build. I need to create this tensor. I'd like to be able to just fill in a blank tensor with specific components.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols

I'm also VERY new to Python, so please be specific!

Comment: Why don't *you* be specific! Simply linking to a Wiki page is not going to be enough to get you an answer here. At the very least you need to explain exactly what your input parameters and your desired outputs are. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at SymPy's differential geometry module (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/diffgeom.html).